# google drive: new chat-style comments

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an API to add/edit/control new chat-style fancy comments in Google Drive (Google Docs)?

I would like to automatically add a new comment to a given cell from the user running the script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet. The getComment(s) and setComment(s) methods on a range deal with what are now called Notes, not Comments. Hopefully Google adds methods for the new comments soon.